# Laravel 5 Paginator returns first page only

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination

I have a fairly simple chatlog viewer which uses a Laravel paginator to easily separate the returned logs into pages. Unfortunately, the paginator only ever returns the first page of results, even though it renders the number of pages correctly.

Here's the controller code:

```
public function search(Requests\ChatSearchRequest $request)
{
    //split search up into what we've got

    $request->flash();

    $nick = $request->input('nick');
    $message = $request->input('message');
    $channel = $request->input('channel');
    $time_start = $request->input('datestart');
    $time_end = $request->input('dateend');
    $sortby = $request->input('sortby');
    $limit = (int) $request->input('limit');
    $page = (int) $request->input('page');


    $query = ChatMessage::query();

    if (!empty($nick))
        $query->usersLike($nick);
    if (!empty($channel))
        $query->fromChannel($channel);
    if (!empty($message))
        $query->matchMessage($message);
    if (!empty($time_start))
        $query->betweenTimes($time_start, $time_end);

    $query->orderBy('id', $sortby);

    $messageResults = $query->take($limit)->get();

    $messages = new LengthAwarePaginator($messageResults->all(), $messageResults->count(), 100, $page, ['path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath(), 'query' => $request->query()]);

    return view('chatlog', compact('messages'));
}
```

And here's what a request generated by the form the page uses looks like:

```
http://localhost/chatlog/search?message=&nick=Saten&channel=&datestart=2017-09-17T14%3A50%3A44&dateend=2017-09-24T14%3A50%3A44&limit=250&sortby=desc&page=3
```

I've tried a bunch of things from other questions asked here to no avail. I've tried using `Paginator::resolveCurrentPage()` in lieu of pulling page from requests directly, no success. Nothing seems to make it work.

Oddly enough, the index view on the same controller which uses a simplePaginate works fine. The form is built with Laravel Collective forms, could it be omitting the csrf_token and making the request bounce at the request side?

Comment: Use paginate() function to create pagination. It is easy to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always take first 250 records for all pages with this query:

```
$query->take($limit)->get()
```

So try just add offset like this:

```
$query->skip($limit*$page)->take($limit)->get()
```

It should skip records for previous pages and you will get only records for current page.

Also you pass wrong data to `LengthAwarePaginator` constructor. Try this:

```
    $messages = new LengthAwarePaginator(
        $messageResults->all(),
        ChatMessage::count(),//total count
        $limit,//items per page 
        $page,//current page
        ['path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath(), 'query' => $request->query()]
    );
```